# The PC stucks after a few minutes

Tags: windows-7, atapi

I've performed some updates which made my Windows 7 PC like this: When I use a PC for ~10 minutes, the PC stops working(Takes a loooooooong time to even shutdown or close programs correctly).

So, I decided to check the event logs.
First it shows:
`The following boot-start or system-start driver(s) failed to load:  cdrom`
Then shows:
`The driver detected a controller error at \Ide\Ideport0`
for about 30 times the same second. And it makes all other windows unresponsive. No CPU usage, no RAM usage. resmon.exe or perfmon.exe fail to load 'disk info' during this time.

So, I went into safe mode. It works perfectly in safe mode - No errors in the event log or no glitches (Driver error).

So, I reinstalled all the drivers thru the driver manager - no hope.
Uninstalled all the installed updates - no hope.
Reinstalled the CD-Rom Driver (It malfunctioned a long ago) - no hope.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to delete your question, the "delete" link is literally next to the "edit" link you used to wreck your post.

Answer (score 1):

Unplug the CD-ROM drive.
Delete the drivers.

Optionally test what happens if you re-connect it & let Windows reinstall the drivers rather than some dodgy 3rd party 'driver manager' - most of which are terrible.
As you said the CD drive failed long ago, I doubt this step will gain you anything - unless it was the dodgy driver manager that 'broke' it in the first place.